# Kafka server is not connecting with zookeeper server remotly

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to connect kafka server (on windows system) to Zookeeper server. I am facing

```
Opening socket connection to server 10.160.10.25/10.160.10.25:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
```

I am not able to understand how can i resolve.I have tried to more relevant question regarding this but didn't get answer. I have attached log and command as well to connect.

Also port is accessible from client

```
**bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat config\server.properties**
```

**Log attached below**

```
[2020-05-01 16:25:37,082] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-05-01 16:25:37,083] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-05-01 16:25:37,083] INFO Client environment:os.name=Windows 7 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-05-01 16:25:37,084] INFO Client environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-05-01 16:25:37,084] INFO Client environment:os.version=6.1 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-05-01 16:25:37,085] INFO Client environment:user.name=Admin (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-05-01 16:25:37,085] INFO Client environment:user.home=C:\Users\Admin (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-05-01 16:25:37,086] INFO Client environment:user.dir=D:\Software\kafka_2.12-2.4.1 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-05-01 16:25:37,086] INFO Client environment:os.memory.free=976MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-05-01 16:25:37,087] INFO Client environment:os.memory.max=1024MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-05-01 16:25:37,087] INFO Client environment:os.memory.total=1024MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-05-01 16:25:37,099] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=X.X.X.X:2181 sessionTimeout=6000 watcher=kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$ZooKeep
erClientWatcher$@31c88ec8 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-05-01 16:25:37,192] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.co
mmon.X509Util)
[2020-05-01 16:25:37,357] INFO jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket)
[2020-05-01 16:25:37,393] INFO zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled= (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-05-01 16:25:37,402] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Waiting until connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2020-05-01 16:25:43,416] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closing. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2020-05-01 16:25:46,564] INFO Opening socket connection to server XX.XX.XX.XX/XX.XX.XX.XX:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (
org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-05-01 16:25:46,569] WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 9172ms for sessionid 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-05-01 16:25:46,699] INFO Session: 0x0 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-05-01 16:25:46,706] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2020-05-01 16:25:46,711] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2020-05-01 16:25:46,724] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.$anonfun$waitUntilConnected$3(ZooKeeperClient.scala:259)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:253)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.waitUntilConnected(ZooKeeperClient.scala:255)
        at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.<init>(ZooKeeperClient.scala:113)
        at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$.apply(KafkaZkClient.scala:1858)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.createZkClient$1(KafkaServer.scala:375)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:399)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:207)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:84)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2020-05-01 16:25:46,749] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-05-01 16:25:46,844] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2020-05-01 16:25:46,886] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
[2020-05-01 16:25:46,993] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

**zookeeper.properties**

```
icensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
dataDir=/home/weaver/app_server/zookeeper
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# disable the per-ip limit on the number of connections since this is a non-production config
maxClientCnxns=0
# Disable the adminserver by default to avoid port conflicts.
# Set the port to something non-conflicting if choosing to enable this
admin.enableServer=false
# admin.serverPort=8080
```

**server.properties**

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# see kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from 
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092

# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, 
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092

# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details
#listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

# The number of threads that the server uses for receiving requests from the network and sending responses to the network
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads that the server uses for processing requests, which may include disk I/O
num.io.threads=8

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=1

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to excessive seeks.
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=168

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining
# segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=10.160.10.25:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000


############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

# The following configuration specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial consumer rebalance.
# The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to a maximum of max.poll.interval.ms.
# The default value for this is 3 seconds.
# We override this to 0 here as it makes for a better out-of-the-box experience for development and testing.
# However, in production environments the default value of 3 seconds is more suitable as this will help to avoid unnecessary, and potentially expensive, rebalances during application startup.
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

Comment: Why don't you share `server.properties` and `zookeeper.properties`? Also, in the title you mention Kafka client and in your answer you haven't mention any client at all.

Comment: Thanks @GiorgosMyrianthous, Apologies for mistake, I Have change title i need to connect kafka server to zookeeper server and also attached server and zookeeper property file.

Comment: Is Zookeeper up and running?

Comment: yes it is running and port also open

Comment: kapil joshi - Is this error resolved? Even I'm facing similar error.