# Kafka + Spring locally broker may not be available. Windows 10

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm having trouble configuring kafka and spring on Windows 10 machine.

I did according to the guide, which I found on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IncG0_XSSBg&t=538s.

I can't connect locally in any way.

The spring application is very simple and its task is only to connect to the standing server.

I have already spent a lot of time looking for a solution and nothing helps me.
I tried a lot. changed it to
server.properties
*listenera na listeners = `PLAINTEXT: //127.0.0.1: 9092`.*
*I changed Java version to `jre 8.241`.*

The spring application cannot connect to the broker.

Please help.

[image: spri]

UPDATE

After typing, to start Kafka server:

`bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`

I have got following error:

[image]

Comment: After running zookeeper in your terminal, did you also run kafka cluster? Because it looks like no connection with port 9092

Comment: How can I do this? In the tutorial it had not been mentioned.

Comment: I have run only bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties

Comment: I have shared a simple bootstrap on Windows [here](https://github.com/gorestrun/bootstrap-kafka-on-windows). You might want to check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you run zookeper, open another terminal, change directory to again where you run zookeper, and then run command `bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`. This will start kafka server, and you will be able to reach `9092` port.

For details, you can see quick start [doc.](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart)

Comment: Thank You. I have got another error. Can You help me ?

Comment: In which order did you start them? First zookeper should be started, and then in separate terminal kafka should be started. Please compare your steps with the ones in docs I shared in my answer (https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart)

Comment: Yes I did this.

Comment: Firstly I have started zookeper and then kafka

Comment: I was looking for solution and just saw this [Kafka server is not connecting with zookeeper server remotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61541349/kafka-server-is-not-connecting-with-zookeeper-server-remotly), and this is not resolved in this question. What i can suggest that just make sure that loacalhost:port options for connection in `server.properties` ,  `zookeeper.properties`  and `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` are pointing same localhost:port option. Apart from that i am sorry i am linux user, good luck